# Akka streams: Why does Sink.head terminate stream with alsoTo broadcast?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Let's take a very simple case:

```
Source(1 to 10)
  .alsoTo(Sink.foreach(v => println(s"each: $v")))
  .toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right)
  .run()
```

According to `alsoTo` documentation, I would expect `Sink.foreach` to print all the elements, however, it only prints first. Same happens if I switch `Sink.foreach` and `Sink.head` places.

If broadcast is implemented via `GraphDSL`,however , the entire source is consumed even if one of the sinks is `Sink.head`.

EDIT:
Documentation for `alsoTo` states the following:

> Attaches the given Sink to this Flow, meaning that elements that pass through this Flow will also be sent to the Sink.

To me this sounds like a broadcast, but maybe this is where I make the mistake. I could also interpret that `toMat` controls the flow. So, I would expect the following to take all elements from the source:

```
Source(1 to 10)
  .alsoTo(Sink.head)
  .toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.right)
  .run()
```

GraphDSL version works as I would expect:

```
val s1 = Sink.foreach[Int](v => println(s"each: $v"))
val s2 = Sink.head[Int]
val source = Source(1 to 10)
RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(s1, s2)((_, _)) { implicit builder => (s1, s2) =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  source ~> broadcast.in
  broadcast.out(0) ~> s1
  broadcast.out(1) ~> s2
  ClosedShape
}).run()
```

Comment: You have to keep an eye on the significance of materialised value. Also share you GraphDSL version. And how is this shared code a broadcast ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `Sink.head` consumes single element and completes itself. This is propagated upstream in the form of a `cancel` and no elements are sent from the Source after this.

Code from `akka.stream.impl.HeadOptionStage.onPush` shows it

```
      def onPush(): Unit = {
        p.trySuccess(Option(grab(in)))
        completeStage()
      }
```

Where `completeStage`

> Automatically invokes [[cancel()]] or [[complete()]] on all the input or output ports that have been called, then marks the operator as stopped.

**Update**

`alsoTo` is a broadcast that is configured with these parameters:

```
      val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[Out](2, eagerCancel = true))
```

Your `GraphDSL` version works differently because by default broadcast is `eagerCancel = false`.

Where `eagerCancel`

> if true, broadcast cancels upstream if any of its downstreams cancel.

Comment: is the only way to avoid this is using `GraphDSL`?

Comment: Thanks, got it now. In case someone else wants to avoid the `GraphDSL` we figured out that `wireTap` configures a broadcast without a cancel